# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop to Ubuntu 14.10 Server

Tags: server, upgrade, vpn

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop successfully installed on a dedicated PC but now wish to install Ubuntu 14.10 Server instead as I want to setup my own cloud server and also an Open VPN server.

Is it possible to do such an upgrade or do I need to uninstall Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop first and do a clean install of the Ubuntu 14.10 Server?

Comment: Desktop to server conversion, i believe you have to go with a clean install..

Comment: Ubuntu server and desktop are the same software, with different options installed. *If you still want to use the GUI, you may just want to install server-related packages.* Alternatively,  you could do a fresh install of server, to more easily add all the supporting elements (for cloud). And then add 'desktop' elements, for GUI. ***Please update your question, or add comment, to identify what you want (and still need to know.***

Comment: As I'm new to Ubuntu, I think a fresh install of the server and then add the desktop elements afterwards would be an easier option for me. Thanks guys.